# Obtener la letra central de una palabra en Python

Tags: python, caracteres

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Python y hasta ahora he logrado obtener la primera letra de una palabra cualquiera, y la ultima, pero no logro obtener la letra del medio.

Es mas fácil si se tiene ya la palabra. Por ejemplo:

Si la palabra es: Hoja

La primera letra es H, la letra central vendría siendo o, y la ultima letra es: a.

En Python seria así:

```
    print("LETRAS DE UNA PALABRA")

    palabra = "Hoja"

    letra1 = palabra[0]

    letraM = palabra[1]

    letraF = palabra[3]

    print("")
    print("Las letras de la palabra [Hoja] son: ",letra1,"-","letraM","-",letraF)
```

Así sería si fuera una palabra fija, pero en mi caso debo obtener la letra central de una palabra **aleatoria** ingresada por el usuario. Y no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Esto llevo de momento:

```
    import time

    print("POSICION DE LETRAS EN PALABRAS")
    print("")

    palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")

    last_p = len(palabra)
    last_pl = palabra[last_p-1]

    first_pl = palabra[0]


    print(first_pl,"-",last_pl)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que dividir la longitud de la palabra en 2 y pasarla a entero para evitar errores `mid_p = int(len(palabra)/2)` luego obtienes el lugar en donde se encuentra la letra `mid_pl = palabra[mid_p-1]` y listo

```
import time

print("POSICION DE LETRAS EN PALABRAS")
print("")

palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ")

last_p = len(palabra)
last_pl = palabra[last_p-1]

first_pl = palabra[0]

mid_p = int(len(palabra)/2)
mid_pl = palabra[mid_p-1]


print(first_pl,"-",mid_pl,"-",last_pl)


time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Se veía mas sencillo de lo que pensaba. Gracias voy a hacerlo así. Aunque no siempre será una palabra de 4 caracteres, 8, 12, 16 o algún múltiplo de 4. Por lo que esa división no siempre dará un valor entero. Pero con tu respuesta ya se me facilito mucho. Gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: Como me arrojaba un error, la linea que le pasaba el calculo de la división a la variable palabra. Tuve que arreglarlo dejándolo entre los corchetes [] así: **[int(mid_p-1)]** funciona al final. Y no era necesario que la linea que divide el len() de la variable palabra, dejarlo como entero. Así: **mid_p = len(palabra)/2**. Funciona tambien. Gracias!!!